# After setting partition size in C drive then restart, whole C drive is reduced to partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu via LiveCD on my desktop, which already has Windows Vista and its `C:` drive has a 320 GB capacity.

During installation, the screen asked me to set the default partition size. Roughly, Vista would have 50% size, say 160GB, and the rest 50% would be for Ubuntu.

Further during the installation, I played with and toggled the button *Continue* and the other one (I forgot the name), but I shouldn't have. The machine froze, so I manually powered it off.

When I restarted the desktop and looked at the `C:` drive size, it only has 160 GB shown.

Should I reinstall or use a partition tool to recover the lost space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot `ubuntu` livecd,connect to the internet and run the below command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

After gparted installation completed,open `gparted` application,find the partition (in which you try to install ubuntu) and format it to `ext4` filesystem.
Then you run the ubuntu installation disk to install ubuntu on that partition.

Comment: Can I resize the partition with a tool? I feel that 50% space for ubuntu is too big.

Comment: with that tool you can `resize,delete` a partition.